# Preview PDF in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, c#-3.0

I'm looking for .NET GUI component (different than [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)) allowing **preview PDF 1-page document**.
Basically I need something similar to PictureBox where I can load bitmaps and show it.

It would be great if that component allows zooming and moving picture inside.
Freeware solutions preferred :)

Comment: Going this track we shall stop posting on stackoverflow as we can find almost everything in google... 
Believe me - I've made research before. I'm interested components what posters tried and found useful / flexible and can advice to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to use the WebBrowser control in your GUI. It's going to use the browser to render the PDF, but I'd do that route rather than mess around with the Adobe Reader ActiveX component.

If you don't want any type of PDF reader available on the client, you could also convert it to a graphic file through GhostScript and display it as a bitmap.

Comment: Good idea! 
Can you give me some tips how can I open it in webbrowser ?
I'm setting webbrowser.URL to eg "file://c:/temp/test.pdf" but it doesnt work - it opens Acro Reader as separate process...
(Same as IExplore...)

Comment: There is also CEFSharp Chromium browser for .net if you don't want to rely on ie/edge MS browsers. https://cefsharp.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

you can use activex component that comes with Acrobat Reader.

[How to render pdfs using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

Question is rather old, but proposed solutions have significant drawbacks:

- WebBrowser control relies on the IE and that it can display PDF documents (this is true only if Adobe Reader is installed)
- GhostScript is licensed under AGPL and it requires rather expensive license for usage in closed source/commercial projects.

Fortunately free alternative exists: poppler tools (based on xpdf codebase) which are licensed under GPL and may be used as console utility. From .NET code it may be executed with System.Diagnostics.Process.

To simplify poppler tools usage we've developed [NReco.PdfRenderer](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_to_image_renderer_net.aspx) .NET wrapper that embeds poppler windows binaries (they're extracted on first use) and provides simple API for rendering PDF pages to image:

```
var pdfToImg = new NReco.PdfRenderer.PdfToImageConverter();
Image firstPageImg = pdfToImg.GenerateImage( "test.pdf", 1);
```

Component is not free, but its pricing is very reasonable.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process still requires Adobe Reader to be installed for the file association to work, but +1 for simplicity.

Comment: @OldDog System.Diagnostics.Process doesn't need Adobe Reader, and poppler tool (pdftoppm) has no dependency on Adobe Reader. It produces image (png or jpg) that can be displayed as any other image file.

Comment: For clarification I was only referring to System.Diagnostics.Process, which relies on a file association to .PDF. Prior to Windows 10, there was no native Windows PDF reader. Even with Windows 10, it uses IE (Edge) as the native reader, which I agree is a drawback. I am currently using System.Diagnostics.Process per your suggestion and since Adobe Reader is IMHO well-written and fairly universally used, and yes free, it suits my needs well due to it's basically single statement simplicity. If you are saying you can use poppler instead, then we just disagree on the association.

Answer (score 0):

[ImageGear for .NET](http://www.accusoft.com/ig-net.htm)

Not free.  Arguably has a larger scope than what you're concerned about.  I hope it's somehow helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Quick PDF Library](http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/products/quickpdf/index.php), my companies PDF SDK, will help you to render PDF files. It's not freeware, but the license allows for royalty-free distribution of compiled apps that you build with it. Finding free / open source components for rendering PDF files is a little trickier than other basic PDF manipulation tasks because rendering PDF files can be quite difficult.

Here is some C# sample source code that shows you how to render the PDF in the picture box on your form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuickPDFAX0718.PDFLibrary pdf = new QuickPDFAX0718.PDFLibrary();

    qp.UnlockKey("......Licence Key......");

    // Open PDF File
    int Handle = qp.DAOpenFile("C:\\sample.pdf", null);

    // Get Total Number of Pages in a PDF File
    int PageCount = qp.DAGetPageCount(Handle);

    int PageNo = 1;

    // It will get Reference of page 1 from PDF file
    int PageRefNo = qp.DAFindPage(Handle, PageNo);

    // You can change this parameter for Zoom In/Zoom Out purpose
    int Zoom = 76;
    double pageWidth = qp.DAGetPageWidth(Handle, PageRefNo) / Zoom;
    double pageHeight = qp.DAGetPageHeight(Handle, PageRefNo) / Zoom;

    // DPI use for rendering the page. Increase DPI will increate quality of image
    int dpi = 92;

    // Calculate Dimension of final output image
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(pageWidth * dpi), Convert.ToInt32(pageHeight * dpi));

    // This will Draw render image on GDI
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    {
    IntPtr dc = g.GetHdc();
    qp.DARenderPageToDC(Handle, PageRefNo, dpi, (int)dc);
    g.ReleaseHdc(dc);
    }

    // Assigne rendered image to PictureBox Control which will display PDF on Windows Form.
    pictureBox1.Image = b;
    pictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
}
```

The library doesn't include built-in functions to help you with zooming, but since you're rendering the PDF as a BMP image you can take care of the zooming fairly easily.

Comment: Looks nice indeed. But easier and cheaper to me is use @bryanjonker's method :)

Comment: Easier and cheaper for you, but not necessarily your end user. ;-)