# Show the first page of a PDF in a form

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a system. and in one form there is a list in the left side and web browser component in the right side. Names of the pdf files are loaded in to the list through a ftp. and when user clicks the list the relevant pdf is loaded in to right side (to the web browser component) but when user clicks several pdf files contentiously it gets loaded all the pdf files from the list. so i want to rebuild it as when the user clicks or mouse over the pdf name from the list just to make a preview,thumbnail in the web browser component without loading all the pdf files. is there a component to do soo?

Comment: Can you provide some code what you tried..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and note that asking for 'components' or libraries or tutorials is off topic for SO

Comment: Welcome :)
I would search: " PDF preview c# " for start. and first (and second) result is StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454721/preview-pdf-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the PDF to images and display the first image.

Comment: How to do like that? I want to just to show the first page of the pdf. so user doesn't want to wait until the full pdf document is being loaded to web browser.

Comment: You can use PDFBox libary

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageNode;


public List<String> generateImages(String pdfFile) throws IOException  {

     String imagePath = "/Users/$user/pdfimages/";
     List <String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
      document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);  //// load pdf   
      node = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages(); ///// get pages
      List<PDPage> kids = node.getKids();
      int count=0;
      for(PDPage page : kids) {   ///// iterate
           BufferedImage img = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB,128);
           File imageFile = new File(imagePath+ count++ + ".jpg");
               ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", imageFile);
               fileNames.add(imageFile.getName());     
           }
           return fileNames;   
    }
```

using PDFBox, and you just have to display the first image.