# C# PDF Control & Library

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm looking for a way to display a PDF (similar to a picture box), in a Windows Form.  After that I need to be able to create a PDF.  What's the best library for the job for creating the PDF (from simple text)? I've taken a look at several and I'm not sure which one is the best. Preferably open source.  As for the control, I tried the COM object Adobe provides... I can't seem to get it working. At all. I've tried loading several files, there are no errors. It simply fails to load.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c

Answer (score 7):

[PDF Sharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/), [Sharp PDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/) and [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) are excellent. They are all OpenSource.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about getting the PDF to render, you could use a [WebBrowser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) on your form as long as the client workstation has Adobe Reader installed.  The browser will automatically pick up the MIME type and load the in-browser Adobe Reader.

For rendering, I echo [Will Marcouiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162167/will-marcouiller) and [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks).  We have had good success with PDFSharp.

Answer (score 0):

For creating pdf's [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) is very good, and it's free too.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with [SharpPDF](http://sharppdf.sourceforge.net/) and it did great job. And it's open source.