# View PDF through C# .Net desktop App

Tags: c#, desktop-application, pdfview

I want to know how I can view a PDF through a C# .net desktop App. I am trying to create a application to view PDF using visual studio 2008

There is a pdf reader libraries called iText(iTextSharp). But it didn't help me

Comment: What does NetBeans have to do with the C# application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can host a ie web browser control in your application and that will allow the user to view a pdf if they have a reader installed.

I can provide an example if you tell me whether you are using WPF or WinForms.

1. Drag WebControl on to you form
   [image: Drag WebControl on to you form]
2. Set the path in code
   [image: set the path in code]
3. Done Press F5

Comment: thanks for your very good explanation. Could you explain how to do it with wpf also. Thanks Again!

Comment: I don't think using a web browser for just reading PDF document is good idea and is waste of memory.

Answer (score 1):

iText isn't a PDF viewer.

If you want to read PDF documents in your application there are couple of [Open Source PDF Libraries](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what netbeans has to do with anything, but take a look at this question here [How to render pdfs using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c)

Essentially you need to get a 3rd party PDF viewer or write one yourself. There are quite a few around and would probably take a look at something like [PDFViewForNet](http://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm)