# PDF Files In C# Resources

Tags: c#, pdf, resources

I want to save some PDF files in C# project resources. How can I get that resource at run time in stream format to show in PDF viewers correctly? Or have you an idea for this
solution, to embed some PDF files in a class library and show them in a free PDF viewer?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Save PDF files in C#'? Please can you elaborate your question a bit further. Thanks.

Comment: In Resources I Mean , To Save PDF ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a web control for viewing PDF read the second answer here [View PDF through C# .Net desktop App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882549/view-pdf-through-c-sharp-net-desktop-app)

Your question is vague be precise for better help.