# PDF Viewer on Metro Style App without launching separate application

Tags: microsoft-metro, pdf-reader

I have found Foxit Embedded PDF SDK for pdf reading without lauching. It is great. It works properly for Metro Style App in windows 8. They also supply demo(sample code).
But they only give 30days trial version only.

I want to know that there is any other vendors or not (free full version).

So , please kindly reply to me

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand there are no decent opensource c# pdf rendering engines.

This question lists some possibilities : [How to render pdfs using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c-sharp)

Most web browsers can render PDFs so you could embed a web browser into your app and hand it the pdf to render:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/embedding-a-web-browser-in-a-windows-8-metro-c-application.htm

I would question why you are doing this. If it is to display content then why is that content a PDF? couldn't it be more useful to the user as an HTML page? If it is to read pdfs that the user provides then why are you embedding? The point of the windows file handling idea is the user has files and applications that open them. If you are overriding this behaviour you make your app worse.

Comment: I am trying to create PDF viewer by browsing PDF with file picker. "Foxit Embedded PDF SDK for pdf" is the most match one with what I want. But it is not full free version. 
For reference : http://cdn04.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/sdk/embedded/FoxitEmbeddedSDKforWinrt2.0.0.821_enu.zip
I have just read the links that you have suggested. Is there any other idea? Please reply to me

Comment: Another idea? Drop it and move on. You'll never be able to create a better pdf reader than foxit/adobe by only using other peoples opensource pdf renderers. I'd re-evaluate why you want to create a pdf reader rather than just open the pdf in any reader that the user has installed. Why are you creating this app? What do the current apps not do? What can you do better?

Comment: I am just the beginner in Metro Style App. I just want to create viewer of every document. Currently PDF. I have found for 1 days regarding reading PDF content and showing that contents. I have found nothing good ideas except oxit/adobe.