# Viewing PDF Files

Tags: c#, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to render pdfs using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c-sharp)

How to view PDF files using c#.net? I only have to view the PDF file, do not have to create or modify.

Comment: Can you assume that the user running your program will have Acrobat Reader installed? Can you request that they do? Or is it a situation where you have no information at all?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c-sharp

Comment: No, actualy i want that my application do not depend upon Acrobat reader installed,

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.
[View PDF files in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37637/View-PDF-files-in-C-using-the-Xpdf-and-muPDF-libra)

It's C# and uses/wraps an open source C/C++ PDF library.
 code and compiled binary can be downloaded from Google. [here!](http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewer-win32/downloads/list)

Comment: Additional information: that particular library wraps either Xpdf or MuPDF. Both are excellent, both are GPL. Meaning your entire project needs to be Open Sourced as well. Something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way for this would be to use a `WebBrowser` control (need the client has Adobe Reader  installed) and navigate it to the PDF file you want to display.

Just use:   `webBrowser.Navigate("file:///" + url);` and you'll be able to display a PDF file.

Comment: Great idea but what if the user does not have `Adobe Reader` installed? The user'll be then forced to install it on his browser so that he'll be able to use the application. Not very recommended yet a good idea. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

may be it will helps you. [See User Control Without Acrobat Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41933/ASP-NET-PDF-Viewer-User-Control-Without-Acrobat-Re)