# Load PDF files from directory in WPF Application - PDFViewerControl

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I am selecting a folder containing `PDF`'s and I want to display those `pdf`'s in the `dxpdf` viewer.

This is my code for **Load Button**:

```
private void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog{
        Filter = @"PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf",
        InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
    };
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        MessageBox.Show("Kindly Select PDF Files", "Error");
    else {
        var pdffolder = Path.GetFullPath(dialog.FileName);
        PDFSelections(pdffolder);              
    }
}
```

This is the code for **PDFSelections Function()**

```
private void PDFSelections(string pdffolder)
{
    _path2 = pdffolder;
    List<string> pdf = new List<string>();
    string pattern = @"\b(?i)ABC+_{1}[0-9]*\.(pdf)$";
    var matches = Directory.GetFiles(_path2).Where(file => Regex.Match(file, pattern).Success).Select(p => System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(p)).ToArray();
    foreach (string file in matches)
    pdf.Add(file);
    PDFViewer.AsyncDocumentLoad(file);
}
```

The `PDF` files are named prefixed with 'ABC_'

The `Object` to add `PDF Files` from `.xmal` file is 'PDFViewer'

How do I display `.pdf` files in the `pdfviewer`? It can be a single file or multiple files.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @MakarEmelyanov edited the post.

Comment: Are you using some kind of package at the moment with the program? From googling around, I found this that may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c-sharp

Comment: I am able to view a pdf file using the <Grid> in .xmal file and Open -> PDF I need to populate the grid with the files from the directory i am selecting.

Comment: So you want the grid to be like explorer dialog but within your program?