# Open docx and pttx in c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, document, docx

Is there any way to open .docx and .pttx file in unity for read only?

Example from pdf I can do each site as texture and user can read in this way.

Any ideas?

Comment: are these .docx and .pttx ever changing? If not you can simply convert them to a image format (PNG,JPG etc), then in Unity set the PNG image to a 2d Sprite which will allow it to import them in to the game scene. If these files are changing, then you would need some C# or JS code to convert your existing file to an image before it can be rendered in game.

Comment: Never changing but convert every file is to slow. Application must open file faster. Convert then open then sprite take to many time.

Comment: This should give you a bit more of an indication:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518878/how-to-render-pdfs-using-c-sharp