# Adding a PDF to my visual studios form

Tags: c#, pdf

So I am adding a help manual to my form and would like it to open a pdf in a separate window. Right now I am using this

```
private void helpToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    startInfo.FileName = @"Filepath";
    process.Start();
}
```

But it obviously requires the full filepath. I want to include the pdf with the finished product and thus I won't know the full filepath on their system. I'm not sure if I can add this as a resource somehow? Sorry if I'm overlooking something simple.

Comment: What is the environment?  Web or windows forms?

Comment: Hey, I actually figured it out. It was a windows form. Thanks anyway!

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28028163/1016183 details an answer for WinForms