# How to show a pdf file in picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, picturebox, pdf-viewer

I want to show a pdf page in the picturebox. Is it possible to do that? if not is there any other way out where i can show the pdf page inside the windows form in visual studio?
Thanks

Comment: pdf is only visible in its compatible viewer. in picturebox you can set its icon and on click you can open it

Comment: @AmitRanjan That's not what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. A [`PictureBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.aspx) can only display a [`System.Drawing.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx), which a PDF is not.

Instead, you should be [searching for a Winforms PDF viewer](https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms%20pdf%20viewer).

- [.NET open PDF in winform without external dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549504/net-open-pdf-in-winform-without-external-dependencies)

Comment: I honestly have no idea!!! (exclamation points repeated for reciprocity) My first step would be to search for it - just like yours should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using **Ghostscript.NET** (Ghostscript library wrapper for .NET).

Take a look at this blog: **[How to use Ghostscript.NET library to render PDF's directly to the screen](http://habjan.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-use-ghostscriptnet-library-to.html)**

You can download Ghostscript.NET from here: https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/