# What Activex control component is added by Interop.AcroPDFLib (Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0)?

Tags: .net, winforms, activex

I followed instructions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/555695/1123020

As described I added the:

[image]

Then I wanted to:

> Then you just drag it into your Windows Form from the Toolbox.

but I cannot see any Activex control added to my toolbox.

Did I added the wrong library? I wanted to have Activex control where I can (later on) display PDF and search it in my way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not the correct procedure if you *also* want a control that you can drop on a form.  Which requires a wrapper that derives from the AxHost class.

Short from running AxImp.exe from the command line, the correct way is to right-click the toolbox, select "Choose items".  Pick the COM Components tab and select "Adobe PDF reader".  You can now drag the added control onto your form.  When you do, you now get *two* interop library reference added to your project.  AcroPDFLib, like you had before.  And AxAcroPDFLib, the wrapper that takes care of the control.

Do keep in mind that the target machine needs to have Adobe Reader installed.